# Filter Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ntaccount1 | select Name | Sort Name
```

The above command displays the Names of all the AD groups an active directory account is in. I tried to add `-Filter` to the end but it does not work. How can I filter out the results to only display things that contain a certain string?

Edit: I tried one solution posted below but I want the output to be just the AD group without any titles or heading. It currently looks like this:

```
Name
-----
group_here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no provider filter parameter for `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMemebership`, so you'll have to use late filtering:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ntaccount1 |
 select Name | 
 Where-Object {$_.name -like '*certain string*' } |
 Sort Name
```

Edit - If you just wanted the names:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ntaccount1 |
 select-ExpandProperty Name |
 Where-Object { $_ -like '*certain string*' }|
 Sort
```

Comment: This works. Were you forgetting a close bracket at the end? } . Anyway, it ouputs in column view with a heading and everything, is there a way to scrap the heading and just have it output the listing? See my OP for example.

Comment: I did miss that last curly brace.  Fixed, and updated the answer to just get the names.

Comment: Okay. That works. You're missing a " | " after Name.

Comment: My keyboard hates me today :(.